# async test does not run in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I am trying to test an async function. Thus, I have an async test. When I use pycharm to set breakpoints in this test, they don't break. The things which are supposed to print to console do not print. And, the test takes 0 seconds. pytest lists the test as `PASSED`, but it clearly isn't actually executing the code in context.

Here is the code:

```
import unittest.mock
import pytest
from app.listener import ListenerCog


class ListenerCogTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create a mock discord.Client object
        self.client = unittest.mock.Mock()

        # Create a ListenerCog instance and pass the mock client as the bot attribute
        self.listener_cog = ListenerCog(self.client)

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_on_ready(self):
        # Call the on_ready method of the ListenerCog instance
        await self.listener_cog.on_ready()

        # Assert that the "Running!" message is printed
        self.assertIn("Running!", self.stdout.getvalue())
```

What I've tried:

- enable `python.debug.asyncio.repl` in pycharm registry
- add arguments to pytest including `--capture=no -s` and `--no-conv`

Nothing seems to be working. Would really appreciate some guidance here if anyone is accustomed to debugging async tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [pytest-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/) documentation:

> Note that test classes subclassing the standard unittest library are
> not supported. Users are advised to use
> unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase or an async framework such as
> asynctest.

Did you consider removing the `unittest.TestCase` inheritance and rewriting your test class without it?